# Remote LSP unable to find texlab server

Tags: latex, tramp, lsp, remote

I need to setup lsp to work on LaTeX file in a remote machine. I installed texlab both in local and in remote machine and add the path to the remote texlab in my emacs (spacemacs) init file as follow:

```
  (with-eval-after-load "tramp" (add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path "~/.cargo/bin"))
  (setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":~/.cargo/bin/"))
  (setq exec-path (append exec-path '("~/.cargo/bin/")))
  (require 'lsp-latex)
  (setq lsp-latex-texlab-executable "~/.cargo/bin/")

  (with-eval-after-load "tex-mode"
    (add-hook 'tex-mode-hook 'lsp)
    (add-hook 'latex-mode-hook 'lsp))
```

I still get this from lsp: LSP: `The following servers support current file but do not have automatic installation: texlab-tramp. Command "texlab" is not present on the path.`

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

`tramp-remote-path` might be cached, so I recommend to apply `M-x tramp-cleanup-all-connections`.

The last entry in `exec-path` shall be `exec-directory`, so you must add your directory differently. Something like

> (setq exec-path (cons "~/.cargo/bin/" exec-path))

However, I'm not sure it is used for remote processes. If everything fails, write a message to `tramp-devel@gnu.org`, perhaps we could help you there.

Comment: nothing changes, still the same error

Comment: FTR, after discussion on the Tramp ML it turns out to be a configuration problem at user side.